# Open Sets confusion

Tags: general-topology

This might be a trivial question, but if we are given some $X$ as an infinite set. Consider the finite complement topology, $\forall x\ne y\in X$, why is the set $U = X-\{y\}$ still open?

Comment: Where does $x$ $($from $x\neq y)$ come into play?

Comment: Can you define precisely what you mean by the finite complement topology? Because my understanding of it ([and the definition here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness)) lead me to see that $U$ has finite complement $\{y\}$, and is therefore open as a result.

Comment: @Mark, yes this is the explanation I was looking for thank you. That wiki page is the definition I am working with.

Answer (score 1):

The set $U = X\setminus\{y\}$ will be open because its complement, $U^c = \{y\}$, is finite.